# Contact form is not sending the name

Tags: javascript

I have built this contact form for my website
but I am not getting the name in the email the contact form sends to me.
Also the contact form is super slow and I get the emails after a long delay of about 5-10 minutes every time I send a lead in the contact form.
Is this something I can fix?
I am using word press. Is it the problem/.

```
        <div class="span4" id="fc">
            <?php 
            $action = ( array_key_exists( 'action', $_REQUEST) ? $_REQUEST['action'] : "" );
            if ($action=="")    /* display the contact form */ 
            { 
                ?> 
                <h6 class="form_head">לפרטים / רכישה חייגו : 077-41-800-74 או מלאו את הטופס</h6>
                <form class="cf" action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="submit"> 
                    <div class="half right cf">
                        <input type="text" id="input-name" placeholder="שם*" name="name" required>
                        <input type="email" id="input-email" placeholder="אימייל" name="email" >
                    </div> 

                    <div class="half left cf">

                        <input type="text" id="input-subject" placeholder="פלאפון*" name="message" required>

                        <input type="submit" value="קבל מידע נוסף" id="input-submit" name="submit">



                    </div> 

                </form>

                <?php 

            }  

            else                /* send the submitted data */ 

            { 

                $name=$_REQUEST['name']; 

                $email=$_REQUEST['email']; 

                $message=$_REQUEST['message']; 

                if (($name=="")||($message=="")) 

                { 



                } 

                else{         

                    $from="From: $name<$email>\r\nReturn-path: $email"; 

                    $subject="Message sent using your contact form"; 

                    mail("xxx@gmail.com", $subject, $message, $from); 

                    header('Location: http://newoffice.co.il/%D7%AA%D7%95%D7%93%D7%94-%D7%A9%D7%A4%D7%A0%D7%99%D7%AA-%D7%90%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%A0%D7%95/');

                    exit();

                } 

            }   

            ?> 

        </div>
```

Comment: _i am using wordpress.._ Then why not use [CF7](https://ru.wordpress.org/plugins/contact-form-7/)?

Comment: You may not want to post your business email address on here.

Comment: @hindmost because it doesn't give me customize options